# nginx not running that displays 404 message

Tags: nginx

I've been following the directions based on http://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-configure-femp-stack/

So far when I ran my ip address http://ip address 
I got an error that says "404 not found." 
I've already enable sysrc nginx_enable=yes and that one works
Next I tried nginx -t and that part works and it says:
nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Then I tried nginx result and it it didn't work and I got the message saying "invalid option: "result"" it didn't work then I tried service nginx start and 
it start running and when I type my ip address I kept getting 404 message.

Comment: Typing `http://ip` will connect to port `80` on that `ip`. Is `nginx` listening on port `80` of that `ip`? Chances are, something else is running on port `80` such as `apache` which has no root. Without any posted configuration, it is impossible to guess what is happening.

Comment: I have no clue I was basically following the direction of   http://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-configure-femp-stack/ and I only got stuck on when typing the  http://ip and I was following the step 3 that says Configure Nginx

Comment: If `/usr/local/www/nginx` doesn't exist, you will get a 404. If `index.html` or `index.php` or `index.htm` doesn't exist in `/usr/local/www/nginx` you will also get a 404

Comment: When following installation and configuration guide, you can;t just keep typing and copying without trying to understand what it does. You will end up not knowing what's going on. You will end up clueless and not learn anything new.

Comment: I just check the folder of /usr/local/www/nginx and it is inaccessible

Comment: Good. You found the problem. Cheers.

Comment: what should I do when the folder is inaccessible, how do I enable the /usr/local/www/nginx  to make it accessible since I don't see any instruction on http://www.ostechnix.com/install-phpmyadmin-apache-nginx-freebsd-10-2/

Comment: Earlier, you never mentioned about `apache` and you were working on `nginx`. Now it has grown and `apache` got involved. What's next, `mysql`? If you want to learn something new, try to understand every step. I know what you missed in the guide but StackOverflow is **not for reading comprehensions**. Go back and redo everything you did and this time, understand what each step does.